# JSON Array of Associative Arrays structure

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im not sure if this would be considered proper format of a json structure. Essentially what Im trying to have is an array of associative arrays. My json data:

```
{
"notifications": [{
    "notificationid": "7hstyans",
    "notificationtitle": "Some alert title",
    "notificationtype": "SPECIAL ALERT",
    "dateCreated": "1502203175"
}, {
    "notificationid": "9ksh7dh2",
    "notificationtitle": "This is a old notification",
    "notificationtype": "OLD ALERT",
    "dateCreated": "1502138431"
}, {
    "notificationid": "iksnudo3",
    "notificationtitle": "new notification",
    "notificationtype": "SOME ALERT",
    "dateCreated": "1501000523"
}]
}
```

I am looking for a way to access it such as `data.notifications[0]["notificationid"]`

Would this be considered the correct format for json and the correct way to access it or what would be the best approach to format this?

Comment: If you want to know if you have valid JSON, just check it in [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/). And if you want to know if a certain way of doing something works, try it yourself.  When you run what you suggested, does it work?  Yes?  Well, there's your answer.

Comment: data.notifications[0].notificationid

Comment: read about `json_decode` , either to associative array, or to `stdClass`. But : not both as you have it here. Pick one, decode your json, then use the appropriate syntax for the decode-style you picked.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).
Example:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
echo $data['notifications'][0]['notificationid'];
```

Comment: Usually "json_decode" decodes the json_string into an object. What "true" param does here is that it outputs the json_string into an associative array.